# PhantomJS : Modifiy dom before rendering page

Tags: dom, phantomjs

I'm using PhantomJS 2.1.1
to be able to grab a webpage and generate a screenshot.

It's working... BUT I want do to some DOM manipulation (in javascript) before rendering the page into a png.

What I am doing is (in few step to summarize):

```
page.open(http://my_url.htm), function(status) {
  if (status === 'sucess') {
    waitFor(isPageLoaded, grabPage, 30000); //waitFor function is one provided by PhantomJS in example
  }
};

function grabPage() {
  page.render('screenshot_raw.png'); //this is working well

  page.evaluate(function() {
    document.querySelector('[id^="boardBackgroundImg-"]').style.filter = 'invert(1)';
  }

  page.render('screenshot_remodel.png'); //same screenshot as before

  phantom.exit();   
}
```

When doing myself in a firefox consol, the:

```
document.querySelector('[id^="boardBackgroundImg-"]').style.filter = 'invert(1)';
```

it's working weel!

But into my phantomjs script... it does nothing (but no error).
I've tried to put it in a external js file and use injectJS() or includeJS() but it does not help more.

Is someone having an idea?

Obviously I want to do some little bit more DOM transformation (removing some node).

Regards.

**Update**

I've updated my code to do at the end:

```
fs.write("test.htm", page.content, 'w');
phantom.exit()
```

The file content does not contains the DOM change I've provided.
So it seems that page.evaluate(...) is readonly. Just here to grab data from page content.

Is there a way to modify the DOM before rendering the page in PhantomJS?

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PhantomJS v2.1.1's Webkit rendering engine is rather old now and it doesn't fully support modern CSS or Javascript. Try using [puppeteer](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer) if you can.

Comment: Maybe or maybe not PhantomJS is too old to interpret some css feature. But it's not my poit here. Saving the page content with... fs.write("test.htm", page.content, 'w'); at the end show that the page is not modified. It seems that page.evaluate() is "read only" and do not modifiy the DOM...

Comment: Ok in fact you're right... some other modif are well done. It just my "invert" which is not interpreted :'(

Comment: So, I'm testing Puppeteer, it's working.. but I have the same issue... I'm trying to invert my image color in a page.evaluate with this statement "bgImage.style.filter = 'invert(1)';"  ... and it does nothing. Instead, if I remove the node with this statement: "bgImage.parentNode.removeChild(bgImage);" ... it's working well. So my page.evaluate(... ) is working fine.. juste the change style which not. Do you have any idea?

Comment: Please create a new question for your Puppeteer script, preferably with real URL so I could try to help.

Comment: Ok I've finished with it. It just Chrome which does not support css filter on svg element. I have to dynamically create a svg filter and apply it to do the same...